# Accessing a SafeArray of Variants with JNI

Tags: com, java-native-interface, variant, safearray

I have a VB6 ActiveX DLL with functions that return a Variant. The Variant contains an array of node Variants, each of which contains a string Name and two data arrays (string and double). I am attempting to return this to a Java program as a jobject through JNI.

I can access the outer array of nodes by calling the appropriate VB function and storing the Variant result as a SAFEARRAY. It can access the dimension and get lower and upper bounds. However, I cannot access each node through SafeArrayGetElement() or SafeArrayAccessData(). I always get an Invalid Argument exception.

1) Can I pass or cast the SAFEARRAY (or VARIANT) directly to a jobject without iterating through the nodes in C++?

2) Am I using the wrong parameters to get the SAFEARRAY data? Does the size of the access pointer (var) need to be allocated beforehand?

```c
    SAFEARRAY* outarr = t->VBFunction(&bstrparam).GetVARIANT().parray;

//Returns correct dimension (1)
    printf("JNI GetNodes_States: Got array, dimension %d\n", outarr->cDims);

//Returns correct bounds
    LONG lBound, rBound;
    SafeArrayGetLBound(outarr, 1, &lBound);
    SafeArrayGetUBound(outarr, 1, &rBound);
    printf("JNI GetNodes_States: Bounds [%d, %d]\n", lBound, rBound);

//Returns Invalid Argument error (hresult=0x80070057)
    //Gets first element
    LONG* indexArray = new LONG[outarr->cDims];
    for(unsigned short i=0; i<outarr->cDims; ++i)
        indexArray[i] = 0;
    _variant_t var;
    hresult = SafeArrayGetElement(outarr, indexArray, (void*)&var);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hresult)){
        printf( "JNI GetNodes_States: %s, %d\n", "", outarr->cDims);
    }
    else {
        printf( "JNI GetNodes_States Access Error:%X\n", hresult);
        outobj = NULL;
    }

    delete[] indexArray;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the bounds reported by `SafeArrayGetLBound` and `SafeArrayGetUBound`?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can I pass or cast the SAFEARRAY (or VARIANT) directly to a jobject without iterating through the nodes in C++?

Absolutely not, I'm afraid. You're going to walk through the array, extract all the necessary values, and convert each of them to something that Java will understand.

> 2) Am I using the wrong parameters to get the SAFEARRAY data? Does the size of the access pointer (var) need to be allocated beforehand?

The most suspicious argument is `indexArray`, which you're setting to 0 for each dimension. However, if the array was created by Visual Basic it is quite possible that it is a 1-based array instead of a 0-based array, which would make an index of 0 illegal.

This is why your element-extraction code needs to pay attention to the results of `SafeArrayGetLBound` and `SafeArrayGetUBound`.

Comment: The bounds returned were 0 and 8 for a 9-item long array; I didn't even think about VB arrays being indexed differently. 

I tried using an index of 1, but that resulted in the same error.